# Error while reading very large files with spark csv package

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-csv, univocity

We are trying to read a 3 gb file which has multiple new line character in one its column using spark-csv and univocity 1.5.0 parser, but the file is getting split in the multiple column in some row on the basis of newline character. This scenario is occurring in case of large file.

We are using spark 1.6.1 and scala 2.10

Following code i'm using for reading the file :

```
sqlContext.read
    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .option("header", "true") 
    .option("inferSchema", "true")
    .option("mode","FAILFAST")
    .option("escape","\"")
    .option("qoute"."\"")
    .option("parserLib","univocity")
    .load("abc.csv")
```

java.lang.exception: FAILFAST at 01/20/2015 .

**Sample File :** 
"A AAAAAAAA","AA999","AA999","AA999","9999-99-99-99.99.99.999999","AAAAAA99","Aaaaa Aaaaaaaa

99/99/9999 - AAA
Aaaaaaa Aa: aaaaaaaaa aa A aaaaa, aaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa

Aaa aaaaa aa AAA aaa aaaaaaaaaaa

99/99/9999
Aaaaa aaaaaa - aa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaa aaa aaaaaa aa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaa aa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa.

99/99/9999
Aaa'a aaaaaa a/ aaa aaaaaaa - AAA aaaaaaaaa aaa'a aaaaaaa

99/99/9999
AAA aaaaaa - aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa

99/99/9999
AAA aaaaaa.  Aaa aaaa Aa. Aaaaaa Aa: aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaa, A aaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaa, aaaaa aaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaa (aaaa aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa).  A&Aa aaaaaa aa aaaaaaaaaa aaa aaaa aaaaaa aaaa aaaaa aa aaaaaaaaa, A aaaaaaaa aaaaa aaa aaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaa aaaaa aa aaaaaaaaa.  Aaa aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaa aaaaaa.

99/99/9999 - aaaaa aaaaaaaa.

99/99/9999 - AAA

99/99/9999
AAA aaaaaa aaaaa aa Aaa 9999 aaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa - aa A&Aa.  Aaaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaa.

99/99/9999
AAA aaaaa aaaaaa - aa aaaaaaa aa aaaaa aaaaaa aa AAA aa AAA aaa aa aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaa.  Aa aaaaaaaa aa aaaaaa A&Aa aaaaa aa aaaaa aaaaaaa.

99/99/9999 - Aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaa.  Aaaaaaaa aaaa aaaa 99/99/9999 - 99/99/9999

99/99/9999 - aaaaaa aaaaaaa aa AAAA aa: AAAA aaaaa aaaa aaaaaa aaaa aaaa aaaaa aa aaa aaaaaaaaa.

99/99/9999
Aaaaaa a/ aaa aaaaaaa.  Aaaa aaaaaaaa aa aaaaaaaaaaaa aa AA.

99/99/9999
Aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaa.

99/99/9999
Aaaaaaaa aaaaaa aa aaaaaa aaaa

99/99/9999
Aaaaaa a/ aaa aaaaaaa aaa'a aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa

99/99/9999
AAA aaaaaa A&Aa aaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaa aaaaaa

99/99/9999
AAA aaaaa aaaaaa - aaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaa aa aaaaaaaaaaa.  Aaa aaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaa aaaa aaaaaa aa aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaa aaaa aa aaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa A&Aa aaa aaaaaaaaa, aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa.

99/99/9999
AAA aaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaa aa Aaa 9.  A&Aa aaaaaa aa aaaaa aaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaa, aaaaaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaa aaa aaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaa.

99/99/9999
AAA - aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa.

AAA aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaa aa aaaa aaaaaa aa aaaaaaa aa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aa aaaaaaaaaaa aa aaaa.

99/99/9999
AAA aaaaa aaaaaa - Aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaa aa 99/99/9999 aaaaaa aaaa aaaa aaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaa a/ aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa.  Aaa aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaa aa 99/99/9999 aaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaa 99/99/9999 aaaa aaa aaaaaaa aa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa, aaaaaa AAA aa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aa aa 99.  Aa aaa aaaaaaa aa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa, aaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa.

99/99/9999
AAA aaaa aaaaa - AAA aaaaaaa aaaa A&Aa aaaaaaaaaa aa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaa aaaa aaaaaaa aa Aaaaa 9999.

Aaaaaaaaa aaaaaa aa aaaaa aa aa Aaa 9, 9999 aaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaa aaa aaaaaaaa aaaa Aa. Aaaaaaaa aaa aaaa aaaaaa aa aaaaaaa aaaaaa aa A&Aa aaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaa aaaa aaaa.  Aaaa aa aaaaaaa aaa aaaaa aa aaaaaaaaaa aaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaa aa aaaaa aa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaa aa aaaaaaaaaaaa.

99/99/9999
Aaaaaaa aaa'a aaaa AA

99/99/9999 - a/a aaaa aa aaaaaaaaaaaa

99/99/9999
Aaaaaaa aaa'a aaaa aaaaaaaaaaaa

99/99/9999 - aaaa aaaaaa aa aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaa aaa aaaaaaaaaa
99/99/9999 - aaa aaaa aa aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaa aaaa aaaaa aaaa aaaa aaa Aaa 99, 9999 aaaaa aaa aaa aaaaaaaaaa

99/99/9999 - aaaa aaa'a aaaa aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aa aaaa aaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa
99/99/9999 - aaaa aaaaaa aa aaaaaaaaaaaa aa: a/a aaaa aa aa aaaa.  Aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaa aaaaaa aaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaa aaa aaaaaaa aaa aa aaa aaaaaa aa aaaaa.  aaa aaaa aaa aaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaa aaa aaaa Aaaa aaa aaaa aa Aaaaaaaaa.  Aaaa aaa aa aaaaa a/a aaaaa aaaaa.  Aaa aaaaaa aa aaaa aaaaa aaaaa.

99/99/9999 - Aaaaa AAA aaaaaa aaaaaaaa.  Aaaaaaaaa aaaa aaaa aaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaa Aaaaa Aaaaaaaaaa Aaaaaaaa, aaaaaaa, aaaaa aa a aaa aa aaaa aaaa aaaaaaa aa aaaaaaaa aa aaaaaaa, aaaa aaaaa, aaa aaaaaa, aaaa aa aaaaaaaa, aaaa aa aaaaaaaaaa, aaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaa.  Aaaaa aaa aaaaa aaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aa aaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa (aaaaa aa aaaaaaaaaa aa Aaaa 9999).  Aaaa aa aaaaa aa aaaa aa aaaaaa aa aaaa.
Aaa aaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaa aa a aaaaaaaaaa aa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa, aaaaaa aaaaa aa aaa aaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaa aaaaaaaa aa aaa aaaaaaaa aaaaa aa Aaa 9999 aa aaa aaaaaaa aa aaaaaaa aa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaa.
Aa Aaa 9999, Aa. Aaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa, aaa aa aaaa aaa aaaaaaa aa aaaa aaa aa aaa aaaaaaaa.  Aa aa aaaaa aa Aa. A aaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaa aaaa.
Aaa A/Aa aaa aaaaa aaaaa Aaa 9999 aaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaa aaaa aa aaaaaaaaaa, aaaa aa aaaaaaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaa, aaaaaaa, aaaaaaaaa, aaaaaaaaa aaaa, aaaaaaaaaaaaa.
Aaaaaaaaa:  Aaaaa aaa aaaaaaaa aa aaaaaaa aa aaaa aaaaa, aaaaaaa aaaa aaa aa-aaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaa aaaa aa aaaa aaaaaaaa aa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aa aaaa-aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa, aaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaa.
"

Comment: what is the error you got can you paste full stack here?

Comment: java.lang.exception: FAILFAST at 01/20/2015 .

Comment: I don't really understand the question. The issue does not seem related to the size of the CSV file, but to some corrupt record present in the larger one.

Comment: @maasg I cross verified that record where it was throwing error. Its correct. In fact when i ran this record in smaller file , it worked correctly. So i had a doubt whether there is any limit on the size each column .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark's CSV relation is based on its `TextBasedFileFormat` and only looks at the input on a line-by-line basis, so it does not support multi-line records. If you need to support multi-line records you can look at using `wholeTextFiles` instead and manually parsing the input (but ideally this should be done as a pre-processing data cleanup job).

Comment: Since in our logic we need to apply many transformations and load the data in hive table so we were trying with dataframe.  I was able to load the file by changing the mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize in mapred-site.xml.

Comment: So what is your new loading path?

Comment: I tried to change the mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize during the program in hiveContext.setConf but is not working . Is is possible to change the property in the program itself for such file instead of changing it globally.

Comment: didn't get by loading path ? I haven't done any changes in the code . Just did changes the mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize in mapred-site.xml but can do that for everytime. Need to find a way to change it locallly so that it doesn't impact other jobs.

Comment: Interesting, so your bumping up the minSplit size globally and then it's passing? Do you have a sample of one the multiline records that is now working (because from looking at the code in the current release is Spark I'm not sure how that would fix the problem)

Comment: @I have given a sample record above , the last column has multiple new line character( more than 20 newlines) and can't share the complete record since it has sensitive information. By changing the minSplit size , i'm running it into single partition where i'm replacing all the newline characters  but after that i have do the masking process which will also be done in single partition if parameters are changes globally which we want to avoid as performance will be badly impacted.

Comment: Right so that was my question with the load path, you have changed your code to trip out the new lines manually. You could do the same thing with wholeTextFiles as suggested in my answer, but this does not split within a file. Based on how the text input formats function there is no easy way around this - unless you change your record seperator to something that otherwise doesn't appear or split the input into multiple files your going to run into this problem. You can of course reparation after you've sanitized your input data and this will help.

Comment: Is there any way to change the mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize in code itself and not globally. In cluster mode , i'm able to do by passing mapred-site.xml file in spark-submit but in client mode i haven't got any success.